# Force User to select option from datalist only

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, tampermonkey

i am using a script through tempermonkey on a specific site. i want users to select option from data list only. earlier it was working fine but now it is not working.

Code is

```
P(function(){
        $("bdi:contains('Truck No')").closest('div').next('div').find('input:text').blur(function(){
       var val=$("bdi:contains('Truck No')").closest('div').next('div').find('input:text').val();
        var obj=$("#KASHIPUR").find("option[value='"+val+"']");
    if(obj !=null && obj.length>0 || $("bdi:contains('Vehical Type')").closest('div').next('div').find('input:text').val()=="")

       return false
            else
                 alert("TRUCK NUMBER IS NOT DEFINED");
$("bdi:contains('Truck No')").closest('div').next('div').find('input:text').focusin().select();})})
```

Datalist id Name is KASHIPUR.

WHAT HAPPENED

Comment: Based on the given information: most likely the website changed something, so that your queries won't find the elements anymore.

Comment: @kca Yes Sir, the sites has changed lilbit, i am able to insert datalist in the field but it is not giving error when value is not matching.

Comment: @kca it is giving error in both the cases

Comment: I don't understand, which "both cases" ? What is the error ? Are you able to tell the URL of the Website ? If not, can you copy-paste the section of the HTML code that you want to query ?

Comment: @KCA sir please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760868/error-in-obj-length0-in-datalist-validation i have explained everything here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Obj.length>0 in Datalist Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760868/error-in-obj-length0-in-datalist-validation)

Comment: @kca Sir , Not answered yet

Comment: yes, sorry. I didn't write that comment, that was created automatically when I linked the questions. But I should have deleted or modified the comment.

Comment: No problem Sir, can you help on this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760868/error-in-obj-length0-in-datalist-validation. Actually i am not a coding professional, i have made it by reading online only. so feeling helpless as neither Error is showing nor working

Comment: @kca Sir it not working for the first time, if i backward then forward the page, it started working First time URL https://www.eye2serve.com:9001/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zdca_portal/index.html?saml2=disabled#/Depot-Dispatch-Detail/6527164083 if i backward then https://www.eye2serve.com:9001/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zdca_portal/index.html?saml2=disabled#/Depot-Dispatch-List again if i forward https://www.eye2serve.com:9001/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zdca_portal/index.html?saml2=disabled#/Depot-Dispatch-Detail/6527164083 any idea