# Define a Script to Breakup Single Text to multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, var

I am using a simple script on Tampermonkey to change some value on a webpage.

in the webpage, there is a input value on a input box i.e "FPPUTHP1100000"

This is a material code, The material code structure is as followes:-

F stand for FRESH

PPUTHP stand for PPC

110 Stand For ACS

0000 Stand for MRP.

Material code is not Universal, this could be changed each time.

i want to record it in variables and push a merged text in a empty input box

like ACS-PPC-MRP-FRESH

There are many material code but the basic structure is as above only.

First letter can be F,C,P,D (FRESH,C&T,PDMG,DMG)

Next six letter can be

PPUTHP,PPUSLH,PPUFLH,43UTHP,53UTHP  (PPC,SUPER,WP,OPC43,OPC53)

next three letter can be 110,111,112,113,114 (ACS,VCS,PGU,DGU,AGU)

Next four letter can be 0000 and 5000 (MRP,NON MRP)

Can anybody tell how to make this script.

Answer (score 0):

first of all stor the value in variable by using document. getElementById()

like this...

```
var string = document.getElementById("*replace this with id if input field")
```

now just apply substring functions on this string and save them into the variables like this...

```
var first =  string.substring(1, 0); \\ this will give you the first letter
var second =  string.substring(1, 7); \\ it will give you next 6 letters
var third =  string.substring(7, 10);  \\ it will give you next 3 letters
var fourth =  string.substring(10, 14); \\ it will give you next 4 letter
```

now just apply conditions and make you string like this

```
 let final_string = ""
 if(first == "f"){
  final_string = final_string + "FRESH-"
 }

 else if(first == "C"){
  final_string = final_string + "C&T-"
 }

 else if(first == "P"){
  final_string = final_string + "PDMG-"
 }

 else{
  final_string = final_string + "DMG-"
 }
```

now same apply if-else ladder and add the part to final_string accordingly..

Comment: Hi Sir pls add a little more detail I want to change`$("span:contains('Despatch Detail').text()== "The Merged Text"`

Comment: This is real spaghetti already, and you've only checked the first character. Consider a `switch` case when you have a long list of `if` / `else` conditions to check. Or better yet, use an array or object to organize the data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is always in the order and length you've given, and the conversions are always one of the values you've given, you could create an array with the delimiting points to `substring` the input and then another array with matching indices as a lookup dictionary. Something like this:

```js
let delimits = [0,1,7,10],
    lookup = [
      { C: 'C&T', D: 'DMG', F: 'FRESH', P: 'PDMG' },
      { PPUTHP:'PPC', PPUSLH: 'SUPER', PPUFLH: 'WP', '43UTHP': 'OPC43', '53UTHP': 'OPC53' },
      { '110': 'ACS', '111': 'VCS', '112': 'PGU', '113': 'DGU', '114': 'AGU' },
      { '0000': 'MRP', '5000': 'NON MRP' }
    ];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('input.output').value = delimits.map((delimit, index) =>
      lookup[index][document.querySelector('input.input')
        .value.substring(delimit, delimits[index + 1])]
  ).join('-');
});

document.querySelector('input.input').value = 'FPPUTHP1100000';
```

```html
<input class="input"><button> -> </button><input class="output">
```

And if you want the output in a different order than the input, you can just:

```
orig = output.split('-');
reorder = [orig[2], orig[1], orig[3], orig[0]].join('-');
```

Edited per OP request. A few other notes from experience:

- DOM traversal is fine if you're only using your own code (although even this can cause headaches when your projects get larger), but it's a really bad idea if you're trying to traverse someone else's code. They could change the layout at any point and break your code. Instead you should use an `id` or `class` or `attribute` or some combination of those to create an explicit identifier.
- Everything is asynchronous now days. When writing code on top of other code (tampermonkey, greasemonkey, ect), it's possible that your script executes before the elements you are trying to access have even loaded, which makes it seem like your script isn't doing anything. I'm sure there is a more clever way out there, but I've always addressed this by just wrapping my script in an interval and checking if the element exists / has the properties I want to change before trying to change it.

```
let loading = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.thing-required-for-your-script-to-work').length) {
    clearInterval(loading);
    //your script here
  }
}, 1000);
```

```js
let $input = $('bdi:contains("Material Code")').closest('div').next().find('input'),
    $output = $('span:contains("Despatch Detail")').next(),
    delimits = [0,1,7,10],
    lookup = [
      { C: 'C&T', D: 'DMG', F: 'FRESH', P: 'PDMG' },
      { PPUTHP:'PPC', PPUSLH: 'SUPER', PPUFLH: 'WP', '43UTHP': 'OPC43', '53UTHP': 'OPC53' },
      { '110': 'ACS', '111': 'VCS', '112': 'PGU', '113': 'DGU', '114': 'AGU' },
      { '0000': 'MRP', '5000': 'NON MRP' }
    ];

$input.val('FPPUTHP1100000'); //simulating whatever the page loaded

$output.text(delimits.map((delimit, index) =>
  lookup[index][$input.val().substring(delimit, delimits[index + 1])]).join('-'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- just guessing at the markup based on your code -->
<div><bdi>Material Code</bdi></div>
<div><input></div>
<div><span>Despatch Detail</span><p></p></div>
```

Edit 2, output order:

```js
let $input = $('bdi:contains("Material Code")').closest('div').next().find('input'),
    $output = $('span:contains("Despatch Detail")').next(),
    delimits = [0,1,7,10],
    lookup = [
      { C: 'C&T', D: 'DMG', F: 'FRESH', P: 'PDMG' },
      { PPUTHP:'PPC', PPUSLH: 'SUPER', PPUFLH: 'WP', '43UTHP': 'OPC43', '53UTHP': 'OPC53' },
      { '110': 'ACS', '111': 'VCS', '112': 'PGU', '113': 'DGU', '114': 'AGU' },
      { '0000': 'MRP', '5000': 'NON MRP' }
    ],
    output_order = [3,2,1,0]; //based on the lookup index

$input.val('FPPUTHP1100000'); //simulating whatever the page loaded

let output = delimits.map((delimit, index) =>
  lookup[index][$input.val().substring(delimit, delimits[index + 1])]);
  
$output.text(output_order.map((index) => output[index]).join('-'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- just guessing at the markup based on your code -->
<div><bdi>Material Code</bdi></div>
<div><input></div>
<div><span>Despatch Detail</span><p></p></div>
```

Comment: "It is just Wow" I Really want Something like This Only, can you just Re-Write Code as per my Requirement, in the webpage i am asking for the Meterial Code is stored here `$("bdi:contains('Meterial Code')").closest('div').next().find('input').val()` and i want to change `$("span:contains('Despatch Detail').text()== "The Merged Text"`

Comment: @poolyWriitenCode and no need to click anywhere whenever i open the URL it should change.

Comment: Usually developers want to get paid to `write the code for you`, but fortunately I'm just here to help others learn. Edited my answer per your feedback. I'll also mention that `=` is the assignment operator, and `==` is the equality operator. `$('...').text() == '...'` is checking if the two are equal. In jQuery you don't use the assignment operator here, rather you pass the text as an argument `$('...').text('...')`

Comment: Wow Sir, You are just amazing, Thanks a Lot, as a newbie, i need time to understand it properly.

Comment: Its Working like butter, Thanks Sir, Thanks a Lot, Thanks for giving your precious Time. i am in leaning state this time. lots of thing to learn

Comment: How to use `orig = output.split('-');`
`reorder = [orig[2], orig[1], orig[3], orig[0]].join('-');`

Comment: Added another edit (which is better practice than coding in the comments) to show a simple way to change the output order. Glad I could help, if this answers your question, marking the post as such helps the community with similar questions better find answers as well. Also if you haven't, give [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a read, as you didn't provide any sample code, or what you've already tried, which makes answering questions more difficult and will usually get your question down-voted real quick.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is over with this idea working all the way i thought to be, i also put a question here , pls ignore the subject as the error is not for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760868/error-in-obj-length0-in-datalist-validation, also ignore the answer, they are also not working